# MySQL with two Joins and a Where clause

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables I want to join.

OFFICE contains address/contact details for an office.
CRIMECAT contains categories of crime law that an office may deal with and is related to the OFFICE table via the 'f_id'
CIVILCAT contains categories of civil law that an office may deal with and is related to the OFFICE table via the 'f_id' as well.

An office may deal with categories of crime law, civil law, both or none.

The user puts in a location and also decides via a range of checkboxes which areas of law they're interested in before hitting search. This should then return a list of the addresses of offices that deal with any of the checked categories in that location.

This works perfectly for either a crime category or a civil category, but as soon as one or more of each is selected the query returns zero results.

The working style of query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OF.f_id, OF.acc, OF.add1, OF.add2, OF.add3, OF.city, OF.pc, OF.tel
FROM office OF
JOIN crimecat CR ON OF.f_id=CR.f_id
WHERE OF.id ='3946' AND CR.cat = 'crm'
```

The query I'm banging my head against a brick wall on is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OF.f_id, OF.acc, OF.add1, OF.add2, OF.add3, OF.city, OF.pc, OF.tel
FROM office OF
JOIN crimecat CR ON OF.f_id=CR.f_id
JOIN civilcat CI ON OF.f_id=CI.f_id
WHERE OF.id ='3946' AND ((CR.cat = 'crm') OR (CI.cat = 'aap'))
```

I've also tried using a variant of the WHERE clause which also returns zero:

```
WHERE (OF.id ='3946' AND CR.cat = 'crm') OR (OF.id ='3946' AND CI.cat = 'aap')
```

I'm beginning to think the issue is with the JOIN(s) rather than the WHERE clause but can't think of a better way of writing them.

Comment: Will all offices have a related record in both CR and CI tables? I ask because the join that you specify will only return office records where this is the case.

Comment: No, they may have a related record in one, both or none.

Comment: See the answer posted by David Chan below, it should give you what you want, and was where I was going with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this may help.  i suspect you are looking for either , but you are requesting both

```
SELECT DISTINCT OF.f_id, OF.acc, OF.add1, OF.add2, OF.add3, OF.city, OF.pc, OF.tel
FROM office OF
LEFT JOIN crimecat CR ON OF.f_id=CR.f_id
LEFT JOIN civilcat CI ON OF.f_id=CI.f_id
WHERE OF.id ='3946' AND ((CR.cat = 'crm') OR (CI.cat = 'aap'))
```

Comment: Bingo! Looks like my issue is with JOINS after all and I need to read up on the dark art of LEFT JOIN's. I'll have a browse around the net to satisfy my curiousity but if you have a definition handy of the difference between JOIN and LEFT JOIN (or any other types!) I'd be grateful. Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: when you do a join, only rows which satisfy the ON condition of both sides are returned.  with a left join all the rows left of the JOIN statement are included regardless of whether there is a matching RIGHT half.  a comment is not really enough room to explain, but I hope that helps a little.